# How to configure lets letsencrypt for apache

Tags: openssl

How can I config OpenSSL lets-encrypt for domains?  I have some issues if some post full answer here it would really helpful to me.

I tried this official [documentation](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/), but its not helpful to me.

> Note: OS Ubuntu 18.04

And I need to know how to add vhost for `apache2`

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python-certbot-apache
```

I followed this but no domain name show here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python-certbot-apache
```

before this

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
```

then create a conf file for your website

```
sudo nano your-domain.com.conf
```

this is sample (you can copy paste this and edit doc root and server name)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myweb.com // here my web is my main web site 
DirectoryIndex index.htnl
ServerName bookking.io  //here add your domain name 
<Directory "/var/www/html/myweb.com">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

then CTRL+X then Y 
 then restart apache2  `sudo service apche2 restart`

in this command list out all domain name   like this

```
sudo certbot --apache

Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator apache, Installer apache
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org

Which names would you like to activate HTTPS for?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: bookking.io
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate numbers separated by commas and/or spaces, or leave input
blank to select all options shown (Enter 'c' to cancel):
```

now hit enter to continue